# How to create resizable html5 canvas for javascript bouncing ball?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a rotating bouncing ball using javascript inside an html5 canvas. I want the canvas to fit the browser window width and height, while being resizable

From researching a solution I have landed on two seperate sections of javascript code but I am not familiar enough with javascript to merge them in a way to make this work

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">
    <h1>Bouncing Ball</h1>
</canvas>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height / 2;
    // SPEED
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;

    draw();

    function draw() {

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();

      ctx.arc(x, y, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#9370DB";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();

      if (x + dx > 480) {
        dx = -dx;
      }

      if (x + dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
      }

      if (y + dy > 680) {
        dy = -dy;
      }

      if (y + dy < 0) {
        dy = -dy;
      }

      x += dx;
      y += dy;
    }

    setInterval(draw, 10);
  }
</script>

<script>
  (function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

      drawStuff();
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
      // do your drawing stuff here
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the **draw()** function you're checking if the balls position exceeds the bounds of the canvas.

```
if (x + dx > 480) {
```

and

```
if (y + dy > 680) {
```

Since you want the ball to stay in bounds even if the dimensions of the window have changed we need to get the actual size of the canvas.
Right at the beginning you defined a variable which holds a reference to the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

Using this we can get the actual size by calling **canvas.width** & **canvas.height**.

So the above two if statements become:

```
if (x + dx > canvas.width) {
if (y + dy > canvas.height) {
```

Now if the user resizes the window, the following function will be called:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

As you can see, we're updating the width & height properties of the canvas with the size of the window.

The rest is just combining your two snippets into one - which is not a big deal.
Here's a working example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
// SPEED
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;

var radius = 100;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#9370DB";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - radius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }

  if (x + dx < radius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }

  if (y + dy > canvas.height - radius) {
    dy = -dy;
  }

  if (y + dy < radius) {
    dy = -dy;
  }

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

// resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

resizeCanvas();

x = canvas.width / 2;
y = canvas.height / 2;

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">
    <h1>Bouncing Ball</h1>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Do you know how I might make the ball bounce exactly as the edge of the ball hits the side of the browser window? And secondly why the text within the canvas div is not visible?

Comment: Glad I could help! At the moment our boundary check is around the center point of the circle, so the ball's actual size is completely ignored. I modified the sample in my answer above to take care of this. You'll notice the new variable **radius**. By the way, the canvas is not like other html elements e.g. a `<div>` so the text within the opening and closing tag is displayed if the browser doesn't support the canvas tag. If you want text, you have to use the canvas.fillText() method or layer another transparent html element containing the text above the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change the "bouncing" statement, I would be using radius instead of dx and dy. Like, if x + radius of the circle is greater than width then reverse the direction, in this case your radius is 100 so:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas">
    <h1>Bouncing Ball</h1>
</canvas>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height / 2;
    // SPEED
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;

    draw();

    function draw() {

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();

      ctx.arc(x, y, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#9370DB";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();

      if (x + 100 > canvas.width) {
        dx = -dx;
      }

      if (x - 100 < 0) {
        dx = +dx;
      }

      if (y + 100 > canvas.height) {
        dy = -dy;
      }

      if (y - 100 < 0) {
        dy = +dy;
      }

      x += dx;
      y += dy;
    }

    setInterval(draw, 10);
  }
</script>

<script>
  (function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

      drawStuff();
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
      // do your drawing stuff here
    }
  })();
</script>
```